# Create Column with Reserved Word Name

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have some C# code that creates an Access Database and a sql script that creates the tables and populates them from a C# DataSet object. One of the tables has a column on it named `Memo`. In Access, `Memo` is a reserved word so my sql script fails.

Unfortunately I cannot change the name of the column, but I need my sql script to be able to create this table. Is there something (like a symbol) I can add to the column name to get it to work?

I have tried single and double quotes, but that just names the fields `'Memo'` and `"Memo"` and I don't actually want the quotes in the name. Here is part of the script that I am running to create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE Print_Vehicle (ID Int, Memo VarChar)
```

The error I get is

`Syntax Error in field definition`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to work around this using square-brackets:

```
[Memo] VarChar
```

Although the [official advice](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335) is "Use a different name".

Comment: Ah, that did the trick, thanks. I really wish I could use a different name but changing the name of a field might break 10k of our existing Crystal Reports...